# Finding decorrelation between pd.DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where two columns have almost perfect correlation, meaning when one column has a certain value there is very high chance that the second column will have another certain value, Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
                   'B': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g']})
print(df)

Out[6]: 
    A  B
0   1  a
1   1  a
2   1  a
3   1  a
4   1  a
5   1  a
6   2  b
7   2  c
8   3  d
9   3  d
10  4  e
11  4  e
12  5  f
13  5  f
14  5  g
```

When column `A` has value of `1`, `B` will have `a` - that's a perfect correlation as there is no `A` value of `1` which will have a `B` value different than `a`. That is also the case with `3`->`d`, `4`->`e`.

`5` and `2` are not perfectly correlated.

How can I find all the `A` values who has more than one matching `B` values so I could print them all out?

In this case, my desired output would be something like

```
find_imperfect_correlations(df, 'A', 'B')

Out[7]:
2 -> 'b', 'c'
5 -> 'f', 'g'
```

*EDIT*:
Preferably a generalized answer for when the dtype of `B` could be ints, dates, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_imperfect_correlations(df, col1, col2):
    df_out = df.groupby(col1).filter(lambda x: x[col2].nunique()>1).groupby(col1)[col2].apply(lambda x:x.unique())
    for i in df_out.iteritems():
        print(str(i[0]) + ' -> ' + str(i[1]))

find_imperfect_correlations(df, 'A', 'B')
```

Output:

```
2 -> ['b' 'c']
5 -> ['f' 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUIC, you can

```
In [562]: s = df.groupby('A')['B'].unique()

In [563]: s[s.str.len() > 1]
Out[563]:
A
2    [b, c]
5    [f, g]
dtype: object
```

Or

```
In [564]: s[s.str.len() > 1].str.join(', ')
Out[564]:
A
2    b, c
5    f, g
dtype: object
```

Comment: Looks great! Is there a more generalized way to do so when the dtype of `B` is unknown? (editted the original post) - Maybe the first version of yours is generalized .. ?

Answer (score 0):

This one would also work:

```
grouped = df.groupby('A').B.nunique()
df_grouped = grouped.to_frame().reset_index()
decorrelated = df_grouped[df_grouped['B'] > 1]

print(decorrelated['A'])
```

The first line counts the distinct values in column B for each value in column A. The second line converts the resulting series to a dataframe. The third line selects the rows where the number of distinct values is greater than 1. Then the last line prints the A values.